# Incomplete file sending using sftp UNIX bash script with expect statements

Tags: bash, unix, copy, solaris, sftp

This is a bash script needs to be run on Solaris which takes files from dirlocal, copies to backupdir and sends them via SFTP. The problem is it sends ony 4-5MB of data and then it hangs (somewhere at mput I think) while manually everything works fine. Don't know what to do really...

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=".:../tool/bin:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
dirlocal=</export/home/somedir>
dirlocal_backup=</export/home/somebackupdir>
filename=*
if [ ! -e ${dirlocal}/${filename} ]; then
exit
fi
hostname=<some_ip_address>
username=ftp
password=FTP
remotedir=<somedir>
cd ${dirlocal}
cp * ${dirlocal_backup}
../tool/bin/expect -f - <<EOFEXPECT1 

set timeout 10
spawn -nottycopy -nottyinit sftp ${username}@${hostname}
expect {
     (yes/no) {send yes\r ; exp_continue }
     "*assword" {send ${password}\r ; exp_continue }
    }

expect -timeout 10 sftp { }
send "cd ${remotedir}\r";
expect -timeout 10 sftp { }
send "mput ${filename}\r";
expect -timeout -1 sftp {send "bye\r" }

#send "exit\r"
expect eof
EOFEXPECT1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
rm ${filename} > /dev/null 2>&1
else
echo "something"
fi
```

Comment: this looks like it could be a lot simpler if you configure your ssh keys and use `scp` instead of `sftp`.

Comment: scp can't be used because sftp is required by the customer. I can't do anything to that :(

Comment: Next question - does the transfer take less than 10 seconds? because that's the timeout you put on the expect session

Comment: removed that timeout and added `echo` instead of `"rm ${filename} > /dev/null 2>&1"`. Now it takes about 5 secs and then echoes and exists the script.

Comment: This is how script output looks like:

spawn sftp user@IP  
Connecting to IP...      
Password:
sftp> cd /remotedir
mput *
sftp> Uploading file.csv to /remotedir/file.csv
deleted
the csv file is much more than 5MB.
The final size varies between 3 and 10MB. I guess it is due the connection speed.

Comment: *Sorry for my idiotic text formatting...couldn't figure out how to break lines with two whitespaces.

Comment: you should edit your question to include valuable debug information that is in your comment above. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks ;)
Now, I changed the script a bit and added some timeouts. Not it hangs while "uploading file to" still sending only a small part of data.

Comment: Made it work finally. Edited expect statements were the clue.
Thanks for help! Regards from Russia!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

Made it work finally. Edited expect statements were the clue. Thanks for help! Regards from Russia! – user2107698